# Ruby on Rails: Operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, operators

My application allows the users to search on many different fields and dates to find project records. At the moment, when you select a certain time scale, i.e. (1 year from now), the search returns properly. When you search again with the same time scale and some client, the the search returns properly again. The problems lies when I try to just search on the client. The search returns no results, which is wrong. I'm sure it has something to do with my operators in the search method:

```
def self.search(search_client, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present?  || search_start_date_dd.present?  || search_start_date_A.present?  || search_start_date_B.present?  || search_keywords.present?


todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = ""
    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = ""
end




  where(['client LIKE ? AND (DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", search_start_date_dd, todays_date , search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B, "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])

end
```

I'm sure the problem is in `'client LIKE ? AND (DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND keywords LIKE ?'`

Hopefully someone can see it. Thanks in advance. Just to let you know I'm a rails noob as well :)

EDIT:

Here is my search view, so you understand how the searches work:

```
<h1>Search</h1>

<%# if @project_search.total_entries > 0 %>
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>

Client :
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>


Select start dates from:
<%= select_tag "start_date_dd", options_for_select({
    "Select a period" => "",
      "3 days ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 3.days,   # =    259_200 sec.
      "1 week ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.week,   # =    604_800 sec.
      "1 month ago"  => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.month,  # =  2_592_000 sec.
      "6 months ago" => DateTime.now.to_date - 6.months, # = 15_552_000 sec.
      "1 year ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.year,   # = 31_557_600 sec.
    }, :selected=>params[:start_date_dd] )%>

until now <%= l DateTime.now.to_date %>, or select project start dates between

<%=  text_field_tag :start_date_A, params[:start_date_A] %>

and

<%=  text_field_tag :start_date_B, params[:start_date_B] %>

Keywords :

<%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %></br>

<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
```

Comment: A little tip, when you want to fix issues like these, fire up IRB. Test your assumptions in there, especially when you have a complex query. If it works, then the model is fine, then you can check if you are able to pass variables from the view. Also, have a look at scopes, it will make your code more readable.

Comment: I've only just started learning ROR. I will need to learn how to use IRB i think. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem :/

I just added an else

```
def self.search(search_client, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present? || search_start_date_dd.present?  || search_start_date_A.present?  || search_start_date_B.present?  || search_keywords.present?


todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = ""
    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = ""
end


if (search_start_date_A.blank? or search_start_date_B.blank?) and search_start_date_dd.blank?

where(['client LIKE ? AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])

else

where(['client LIKE ? AND (DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND keywords LIKE ?', "%#{search_client}%", search_start_date_dd, todays_date , search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B, "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])
end
end
```